# How to find elements by the last bit of their ID with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have to find an element by its id with jQuery. This element has the id:

```
txtHistoricalPricesDate
```

which would be easy to find under normal circumstances with the following:

```
var element = $('#txtHistoricalPricesDate');
```

but unfortunately, I'm working in an ASP.NET app, which helpfully renamed the element to:

```
ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucFundSearchResultsPanel_tabContainer_tabPriceTab_txtHistoricalPricesDate
```

rather than dirty the jQuery with that huge ridiculous ID, is there a way that I can tell jQuery to find the element with an ID that ends with `txtHistoricalPricesDate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use a class, or an [attribute-ends-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/), like this:

```
var element = $('[id$=txtHistoricalPricesDate]');
```

If you *must* use the above (but try and use a class) then prefix it with the element type, for example:

```
var element = $('input[id$=txtHistoricalPricesDate]');
```

To use a class, just set its `CssClass` property, for example `CssClass="histPrices"`, then use a [`.class` selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/), like this:

```
var element = $('.histPrices');
```

On any normal element use `class=""`, but since it's an ASP.Net control it looks like, use `CssClass`, as that's *probably* the WebControl property you're dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use a class selector to avoid the ASP.NET id mangling. Simply append a CssClass to your element and then: `$('.txtHistoricalPricesDate')` or if you are using ASP.NET 4.0 you could adjust the [ClientIDMode](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/54760.aspx) to `Predictable`.